# How do you test cache only queries in apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I have a query like this:

```
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_STUFF, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-only",
  })
```

This works fine in the code. In the tests `data` is undefined

but I've mocked it like so:

```
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_STUFF,
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        __a: {
          id: "12",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

but when I change `fetchPolicy` to `fetchPolicy: "network-only"` it then comes through as the expected result.

The problem also is I can't also pass `cache` into `<MockedProvider />` as I have queries on that page that also use `network-only`

How do I solve this or throw stuff automatically into the cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  cache.writeQuery({
    query: GET_STUFF,
    data: {__a: {id: "12"}},
  });

  render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={yourNetworkMocks} cache={cache}>
      <YourComponent>
    </MockedProvider>
  )
```

This is working for me.